# deduce that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{D}$ are dense

Tags: real-numbers

i have a question

let $b \geq 2$ and for $n$ a natural number

$Q_n = \Bigg\{ \frac{k}{b^n} ,k\in \mathbb{N} , 0 \leq k < b^n \Bigg\} $

i have proved for all real number in $[0,1]$. there exists $r_n \in Q_n$

such that $r_n \leq x < r_n + \frac{1}{b^n} $

how to deduce that the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ the decimal numbers $\mathbb{D}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$

please help me with this question with some hints

Comment: (i) Please do not use title lines that are nothing but MathJax, because it disables some navigation shortcuts. (ii) Please do not use formulas that are taller or deeper than usual in the title lines, because it messes up displays.

Comment: What you claim to have proven is false, if $x=1$.